# Replace value in List<List<String>> Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I am trying to replace a value in a `List<List<String>>` in Java and I am facing this error. I am using `List.set()` to do this. Basically in my program I am trying to replace the first element of every list in `dataList` to the variable `x`.

Below is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= dataList.size()-1; i++) {
    String x = String.join("-","Water",dataList.get(i).get(8).replaceAll("\\s","").split("&")[0],dataList.get(i).get(0));
    dataList.set(dataList.get(i).get(0),x);
}
```

} //end main

But I encountered this error "The method `set(int, List<String>)` in the type `List<List<String>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, String)`"

And then I tried converting the sentence to:

```
        dataList.set(Integer.parseInt(dataList.get(i).get(0)),x);
```

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: What is unclear with the `set` method? Its JavaDoc explicitly says, that it replaces the current item on the specifed index with something else. Why do you think you can use it to replace any item which matches `dataList.get(i).get(0)` to `x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must call set on the inner lists, not the list holding other lists.

It is more like this

```
for(int i = 0; i <= dataList.size()-1; i++) {
    String x = String.join("-","Water",dataList.get(i).get(8).replaceAll("\\s","").split("&")[0],dataList.get(i).get(0));
    dataList.get(i).set(0, x);
}
```

You get list number `i` and set the first value (0) to x.

Cheers